# .travis.yml seems not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, travis-ci

I have problems with my .travis.yml file. It is found by travis and i can configure node.js version to test. I have reduced it to one node version, which is enough for my purposes.

As long as i did not try to use mongodb it was fine.

After integrating mongodb (i'd followed the advise on travis-ci.com) it looks for me, that before_script is not used.

(i tried to exchange the install script itself by "echo 'hello world'" just to see some changes, but that did not change anything.).

```
 language: node_js

 node_js:
   - "0.10"

install:
  - npm install

services:
  - mongodb

before_script:
  - "sleep 15"
  - "mongo test --eval 'db.addUser("test", "test");'"

script:
  - "npm test"
```

My last build result is here:
https://travis-ci.org/TheFive/osmcount/builds/51125216

when running the script it looks like, that sleep 15 (and may be the mongo --eval call) is not called.
(what i really want to solve is, to get a connection to mongodb in my testscript, it is recommended in travis-ci.com to wait 15 secconds, to wait for mongodb startup).

Comment: In your test log in travis, it is seen that -the db is not started i.e. there is problem in mongodb connection...

Comment: You should remove the quotes in the `before_script` section. Try with `sleep 15`  and `mongo test --eval 'db.addUser("test", "test");'`

Comment: I had to remove the quotes and the leading spaces before the language and the node_js keyword. After removing the leading spaces the http://lint.travis-ci.org/ website became helpfull in searching the mistake.